# Why does plotting a matplotlib patch corrupt contains_point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

After running the following code snippet,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

plotted_ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0), 10, 10)
unplotted_ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0), 10, 10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.add_patch(plotted_ellipse)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
```

I get the following result when using the [`contains_point`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.contains_point) method

```
In [6]: plotted_ellipse.contains_point((0, 0))
Out[6]: False

In [7]: unplotted_ellipse.contains_point((0, 0))
Out[7]: True
```

This makes no sense to me. Is this perchance a bug? Or is there a preferred method for testing if patch objects contain points?

Using `matplotlib` version `1.5.1`

Comment: Still the same behavior in 1.5.3.

Comment: The transform stack is almost certainly nonsensical for an ellipse that is not added to an `Axes`.  If you want to do computational geometry I suggest shapely.

Comment: @tacaswell thanks for your recommendation, but I think your first statement is lost on me. The problem is with the ellipse that _is_ added to an `Axes`, no?

Comment: your right, I read your question wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are checking the point in the plotted ellipse in data coordinates, while when you add a path to ax its coordinates are transformed in display coordinates.
According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.contains_point):

> The convention of checking against the transformed patch stems from the fact that this method is predominantly used to check if display coordinates (e.g. from mouse events) are within the patch. If you want to do the above check with data coordinates, you have to properly transform them first

So if you wan to check for a point in data coordinates you have to transform it in display coordinates before:

```
point = plotted_ellipse.get_transform().transform((0,0))
print(plotted_ellipse.contains_point(point))
>>> True
```

For clarification on coordinates system see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html).